# Product Attributes Inserting the Print / Invoice

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

How to enter additional information (attributes) in the Print / Invoice

I would like to add other information to print / Invoice.

I want to add.

Name of Client:
TaxVat:
Product Name:
Product Price:
Product Attributes:

thank you

Comment: For attributes, Here is a nice guide:
http://phpmysqltalk.com/1639-magento-add-custom-attribute-to-magentos-pdf-invoice.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/orders/editing_an_invoice_pdf

This should take you through the process of modifying the PDF that is generated by the admin panel